# SAP Crystal Reports: Is it possible to colour a whole group if a subtotal for the group = 0?

Tags: crystal-reports

I am working on SAP Crystal Reports (standalone version).

See the picture for an explanation of what I want to achieve.

Anybody has an idea?
[image: Picture of Requirement]
Thanks
Leon

Comment: I don't do this, but you can try https://answers.sap.com/questions/12582975/crystal-reports---shade-alternate-groups-of-detail.html,  https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1790766

Comment: Thanks Ajay for your reply. I read your links, but they are not really relevant to my problem. Anything else?

Comment: then my suggestion search in google "crystal report detail color based on group condition" and check one by one all link, it will help you.

Comment: I got my answer while playing with the CR Menus. We must use GROUP SELECTION. My formula is:
IF Sum ({Sheet1_.Doc Qty}, {Sheet1_.Client Desc}) = 0 THEN crLime
else CrYellow                                                                                                          
The first { } is the DocQty field. The 2nd { } is the GROUP.                                     
Thanks for your interest.

Comment: very good @Leon Lai